# LibreOffice 4 Skins?

Tags: libreoffice, firefox-extensions, personalization

I read on the LibreOffice [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130212002436/http://www.libreoffice.org/home/Discover#/Discover%20it) that said you could use Firefox Personas on LibreOffice 4. Is this true, or did I misinterpret this?

***Note from a later edit***: The original link is no longer available. This is why it was changed with its copy kept by the Internet Archive WayBackMachine.

Comment: Oh wow! Go LibreOffice! They have now added support (in LibreOffice 4) to open Publisher and Visio files! Score one for Open Source!

Comment: most of them are ugly and useless in my opinion...for what it is worth.

Comment: @Gui indeed, few have been designed with LibreOffice in mind, and probably the less flashy and the less eye-catching work better for LO (e.g., the 'ambiance' ones).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, indeed, customize LibreOffice with Firefox 'personas'.

In LibreOffice, go to the menu **Tools** | **Options**. Under "LibreOffice", select **Personalize** (№ 1 in the image, below).

[image: 'Personas' LibreOffice settings]

Click the button **Select Persona** (№ 2). A new dialog will open. Click the button **Visit Firefox Personas** (№ 3) or visit http://www.getpersonas.com/.

Then you'll have to find a Firefox 'Persona' that you like and copy its URI address back in the LibreOffice dialog (№ 4).

Click "Accept" and you're done.

[image: Firefox 'personas' in LibreOffice 4.0]

Image from [this article](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/02/libreoffice-hits-4-0-adds-unity-integration-persona-theming).

And this is [one I use](http://www.getpersonas.com/es/persona/493881):

[image]