# Download/Save Persona files

Tags: libreoffice, personalization

I love the new features of LibreOffice 4, especially the ability to have a persona installed on it. My favorite is this [one](http://www.getpersonas.com/en-US/persona/493881).

Anyways, I have a midline internet connection, and I was wondering if there was a way I could download and save the image for the persona somewhere where LibreOffice doesn't have to download it every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox 'Personas' consists, simply, of [two image files](https://www.getpersonas.com/en-US/demo_create).

Once you installed one 'Persona' in Firefox, those two files are saved in `~/.mozilla/firefox/[something].default/lwtheme/`; the "[something]" will be different in every system.

However, Firefox is supposed to be connected to the internet for the selected 'Persona' to show, so you either copy those two files elsewhere, or follow [the instructions given here](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Labs/Personas/Saving_a_Gallery_Persona) to download the image files.

And, when you install one 'Persona' in LibreOffice 4, the files are saved in folder `~/.config/libreoffice/4/user/gallery/personas/`.

To reuse 'Personas' in LibreOffice, I've found the [following instructions](http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/12105/persona-offline/?answer=12111#post-id-12111):

**Option 1**:

1. Copy the image files in the LibreOffice `personas` folder
2. Be very careful about this:

   ```
   gedit ~/.config/libreoffice/4/user/registrymodifications.xcu
   ```

   find (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) the line with `PersonaSettings` and change the names of the current files to the ones you just copied. Be careful to match "header" and "footer" file names.
3. Close and re-open LibreOffice.

**Option 2**

1. Rename the files of the current 'Persona' in the LibreOffice `personas` folder (but take note of their current names).
2. Copy the downloaded image files to that folder and rename them to match the previous names.
3. This way, you avoid having to edit the `.xcu` file (which, if not done carefully, might bring a lot of problems).

Comment: The way I "installed" the 'Persona' into LibreOffice 4 via these instructions: http://askubuntu.com/questions/270025/libreoffice-4-skins. When I did follow your answer, it didn't show up in your given location???

Comment: hmm...I only have stuff on LibreOffice 3 there

Comment: Go to menu **Tools** | **Options**; under "LibreOffice" click on **Routes** and find out where your `gallery` folder is.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8023/discussion-between-packpatfan-and-carnendil)