# Can't use personas in LibreOffice 4.1.0.4 on Xubuntu 12.04 64-bit

Tags: firefox, xubuntu, themes, libreoffice

- I go to **Tools** -> **Options** -> **Personalization**.
- I check 'Own Theme' then click on 'Select Theme'.
- I found the theme I wanted, copied and pasted the URL in the "Select Theme' window.

When I click 'OK' LibreOffice crashes. I even tried looking in this folder: `/home/jason/.mozilla/firefox/3yvxv88p.default/lwtheme` to copy and paste the images into the LibreOffice gallery but the images for my current theme are not there.

I have images from a previous theme which are also in the LibreOffice gallery. I can't seem to get personas to work in LibreOffice 4.1.0.4. Any thoughts or suggestions?

I am running Xubuntu 12.04 64-bit.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a bug and you should [report it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug). You may still be able to [install the personas manually](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270962/download-save-persona-files).

Comment: How to [install personas manually also in askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/a/270979/58950):

Comment: @carnendil I didn't see that. I will update the link.

Comment: I can't install the persona manually because the image files for the theme I want to use isn't showing up in the .mozilla folder.

Comment: @JasonSmith, try downloading the persona directly from the website (instructions here: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Labs/Personas/Saving_a_Gallery_Persona)

Comment: Went to the website you posted. Opened a new tab and went to about:config -> extensions.personas.current. The persona showing up there is an old on that doesn't even have image files in the .mozilla/firefox/[something].default/lwtheme/ folder. With that same tab I opened up about:cache?device=disk and looked for getpersonas.com/store/ but I can't find it. Therefore, this workaround doesn't seem to be working for me.

Answer (score 0):

This problem appears to be a [bug](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=59230) that affects some systems.

Apparently, you can still [install 'personas' manually](https://askubuntu.com/a/270979/58950), but the ability to add 'personas' from the menus is malfunctioning.

Source: http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/21421/cant-use-personas-in-lo-4104/?answer=21431#post-id-21431

Comment: Went to the link you posted. I did as the instructions told but when I try to edit the /.config/libreoffice/4/user/registrymodifications.xcu file it won't save my changes. It defaults back to an old persona. So, I deleted the image files of the old persona and renamed the image files of the new persona with the old personas name and no luck. when I restart libreoffice it now shows the old persona which doesn't even have image files in the .config/libreoffice/4/user/gallery/personas/ folder anymore. This workaround doesn't seem to be working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. As it turned out I had files and folders still left on my system from LibO 3 and an earlier version of 4.1. I downloaded and installed the pre-release 4.1.1.1, uninstalled/deleted the old files and personas are working for me now.